# What is the Major Difference between Entity Framework of ASP.Net 4.0 and Entity Classes which is written by developer?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Before entity Framework, Developer was writing the code Entity Classes which is contains the getter & Setters Method for Data Table Fields (Columns).

what is the purpose of introduce Entity Framework, and what's different between Entity Framework and Older traditional way to write down Entity Classes?

Comment: getting data is much more faster in case of Entity Framework...DB hit reduces significantly

Comment: Have you read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not use EF (or any other ORM tool), you will have to write both entity classes and related database operations by hand.

ORM tools creates both entity classes and an abstraction of related DB operations automatically.

In case of EF, it creates entity classes and an `ObjectContext` (or a `DBContext`) which allows you to manipulate DB entities without writing SQL code.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework provides ORM capabilites to Entity Classes. You don't need to craft CRUD or Database operations on database layer, EntityFramework handles it.